# CakePHP calling seq.currval on Oracle when no sequence exists

Tags: oracle, cakephp

When trying to insert a record into a table, I get sequence error:

```
Query: SELECT my_table_seq.currval FROM dual
Warning (512): SQL Error: ORA-02289: sequence does not exist
```

There is no sequence on this table. It is more like a HABTM. I have a table:

```
CREATE TABLE "MYSCHEMA"."MY_TABLE"
(
    "WORK_ID"   NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    "ITEM_ID" NUMBER NOT NULL ENABLE,
    CONSTRAINT "MY_TABLE_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("WORK_ID", "ITEM_ID")
)
```

I manually add both IDs using:

```
$this->MyModel->set(array('work_id' => 1, 'item_id' => 2));
$this->MyModel->save();
```

Any ideas how to prevent the error? Do I just need to do `$this->MyModel->query()` and run the query manually?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the question.  Are you asking how to get Oracle to avoid throwing an exception when your query uses an invalid sequence?  How to populate the data in this table without referencing a sequence?  Something else?

Comment: How to avoid throwing the error? Can it be done? The values show up in the database ok.

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand the question.  If you're issuing a SQL statement that throws an error because it is referencing an invalid sequence name, the obvious answer is to not issue that SQL statement (or issue a SQL statement that references a valid sequence name).  But I assume that you know that and have some complicating factor that prevents you from simply eliminating the SQL statement...

Comment: Are you familiar with CakePHP? When you use `$this->MyModel->save();` it builds the SQL for you. There is nothing I am writing in the SQL that issues the query. This is a CakePHP issue as it relates to Oracle. Not an Oracle issue per se.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CakePHP expects that a join table (as part of HABTM relationship) has its own primary key.

See http://book.cakephp.org/view/1044/hasAndBelongsToMany-HABTM

In your case:

```
CREATE TABLE MY_TABLE
(
    ID        NUMBER NOT NULL,
    WORK_ID   NUMBER NOT NULL,
    ITEM_ID   NUMBER NOT NULL,
    CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_PK PRIMARY KEY (ID),
    CONSTRAINT MY_TABLE_UK UNIQUE (WORK_ID, ITEM_ID)
)
```

And don't forget to add the MY_TABLE_SEQ sequence:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE MY_TABLE_SEQ;
```

Comment: I want a table I can enter data into without a separate ID. I want to use the work_id and item_id as the PK.

Comment: Sorry, CakePHP's magic just doesn't work that way. Maybe you should stick to the workaround you already found.

Answer (score 0):

what happens is that when cake calls a lastinsertid for oracle table, it queries the sequence for that table. if no sequence is provided, it just assumes a $tablename + _seq.

what you can do is that tell cakephp at the model what sequence you are using for that table.

```
MyModel.php

class MyModel extends AppModel{
//in my case 
//my table name was so long it required a shorter sequence name :D
var $sequence = 'my_table_seq';
...
}
```